# Unable to add reference to rzdcx.DLL in C#.Net 4.0 visual studio

Tags: c#-4.0, dll, dllimport

I am trying to send a dicom file to a remote AE, it seems like it could be done instantly with DCXREQ object and Send method from the rzdcx.DLL, however, it didnt work when I was trying to add rzdcx.dll to my reference, it says please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component, what are the possible ways to fix this problem in order to successfully add this reference??

So far I have tried DllImport, the object from the dll cannot be created.
[DllImport(@"C:\Users\Kevin Eger\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RealDicomServer\RealDicomServer\bin\Debug\rzdcx.dLL", EntryPoint = "DCXREQ")]
        public static extern void Send(string localAE, string remoteAE, string IPA, int PortN, string filepath, string succeededFilesList, string failedFileList);

```
    static void main()
    {
        string s = "";
        string f = "";
        DCXREQ requester = new DCXREQ();
        requester.Send();
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to use Tlbimp.exe, run it from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Answer (score 1):

RZDCX.DLL is a COM object.
To develop with it you have to regsvr32 it. 
From command line with admin rights do the following:
regsvr32 rzdcx.dll

For distribution you can check in the references "Isolated COM" so RZDCX can be used in user mode and your users don't have to regsvr32